# How to "extend" query in Lightswitch?

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

I need to present data from two tables in the same view. When I use a calculated property I get a performance penalty that is currently not acceptable.

If I would have done it using only SQL it would be possible using a JOIN. I also know how to do it using linq and entity framework.

The problem is that Lightswitch only lets me execute queries that results in a list of existing entities.

I'm creating a Desktop Client.

Comment: has this been done using the Lightswitch database that you can add in, not SQL Server then? 

and if its the Lightswitch database make sure your relationships between the tables have been added in :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the correct relationships have been set up, it is possible for data items from multiple entities to be displayed concurrently solely using built in queries. Your question doesn't really have enough detail to know whether that would work here, but it's always the best way to go if you can so that you keep the benefit of all the other automagical Lightswitch features.

If it's not possible using built in queries or I really do want to change the shape of the data and not just return Lightswitch entities, I usually use a WCF-RIA service. This sounds like a good approach here as it would leverage you LINQ knowledge too.

http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/2226/Creating-a-WCF-RIA-Service-for-Visual-Studio-2013.aspx covers how to do this in VS2013. It's one of those things that sounds complicated at first but is actually OK if you follow carefully.

Comment: I can't use built in queries only, need a custom entity as the result.

Comment: The solution WCF RIA feels kind of strange, don't know why exactly. I have made my own silverlight component that is shows various summaries on a custom screen. I might as well go all the way and circumvent lightswitch totally and create a parallel connection from the desktopclient that only uses Entity Framework. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: It's only worthwhile using Lightswitch if it does what you want it to do. There's no point shoehorning a project into Lightswitch when it doesn't really fit.

Comment: The problem is that it does fit very well for a whole lot of other things. Like creating the database and inserting data. I would have liked to keep everything in the same application. Then my custom screens could link to normal screens.

Comment: I have created applications where I mixed Lightswitch solutions for admin and frontend with ASP or MVC solutions for other functionality. But I manage the database independently when I'm doing it that way rather than using intrinsic database. And there's so much sandboxing goes on in Lightswitch that whether the kind of linking you want to do would work depends very much on the exact implementation details (and we don't even know at the moment if this is Lightswitch HTML, Lightswitch Web application or Lightswitch Desktop application - all of which behave differently).

Comment: I might as well create a third application for the functionality not possible in Lightswitch :)  Somewhat annoying for the client to have to switch between applications but I suppose better than nothing.